# How to shift blocks right and left (indent blocks) in Joe Editor?

Tags: joe-editor

I want to shift my selected block right and left, I checked the help on Joe Editor's website but it did not quite help. I hope someone can explain better how to indent block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select the block and press <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to move the block to the right or left, respectively.

```
 INDENT
 ^K, less
 ^K. more
```

Comment: Nice! The dot and comma weren't visible enough on the Joe Editor's website.